WEB XR API Emulator always returns fov of 50
I noticed that the Web XR API Emulator for Chrome always returns an fov of 50, even if I change the type of visor from the emulator. I am using Three.js to make a scene and adding vr to it using the vr handler proposed by Three.js.
Is there any way for me to increase the fov of the visor? Both via the emulator or code. I tried changing the fov of the camera array that renderer.xr.getCamera() returns and then updating the camera with .updateProjectionMatrix() but still it didn't change.
Does anybody know a solution for this?
Thank you and have a great day
